# Ubuntu 16.04.05 fresh install, mouse clicks stop working unity

Tags: unity

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.05. Few moments after login in, the mouse clicks stops working on the windows e.g. browser, but I can still click on the launcher and in the tray. If I log out and then log in again the problem might be solved (not always). I have also tried commands like unity --replace, etc. which might solve the problem temporarily.

I had Ubuntu 16.04 before for 2 years and it was working fine in the same computer. After some update the same error appeared, that was the reason of the fresh installation.

I am looking for similar problems but I could not find an answer that helps me.

Thank you for your help.